# Histogram on Gaussian probability density function graph in Python

Tags: python, histogram, gaussian

I want to create a histogram (from pseudo random numbers) with my Gaussian probability distribution function, however, I don't want the histogram to go above the maximum point on my PDF. Here is my code so far:

```
from math import sqrt, pi, exp
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 0.5
variance = 0.5
sigma = sqrt(variance)
npts = 100

x = np.linspace(norm.ppf(0.01), norm.ppf(0.99), npts)

#plot pdf
plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma), lw=3, c='r', label='PDF')

#RNG
y = [-3, -2, -1, 0, -1, -2, -3]
if y < 1./(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(mu**2/2*sigma**2)):
    u = sigma * np.random.randn(100) + mu
    plt.hist(u, histtype='bar', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Does anyone know how to do this or have any clues?

Comment: I can't reproduce this based on the code you've posted (with these imports).`from math import sqrt, pi, exp;
from scipy.stats import norm;
import numpy as np;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: @JamieBull Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

First, you need to use `all(y)` to check all the values in the list meet the condition for creating the histogram.

Second, to make the histogram a similar size to your pdf on the chart you'll need to use a secondary axis since the values are totally different.

```
#plot pdf
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(x, norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma), lw=3, c='r', label='PDF')

#RNG
y = [-3, -2, -1, 0, -1, -2, -3]
if all(y) <= 1. / (sigma * sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-(mu ** 2 / 2 * sigma ** 2)):
    u = sigma * np.random.randn(100) + mu
    ax2.hist(u, histtype='bar', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't create what I want... All the bars are far too high (reaching up to 23). Maybe I didnt explain properly... I want the maximum height of a histogram to be the maximum point on my pdf (so it 'fits' into the histogram)

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Code below works on my computer
`python 2.7.10
numpy 1.10.1
matplotlib 1.4.3
scipy 0.15.1`

but I'm not sure about how you import those function, you should post the code that will raise ValueError so I can answer your question

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from math import sqrt, pi, exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 0.5
variance = 0.5
sigma = sqrt(variance)
npts = 100

x = np.linspace(norm.ppf(0.01), norm.ppf(0.99), npts)

#plot pdf
plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma), lw=3, c='r', label='PDF')

#RNG
y = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
if y < 1. / (sigma * sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-(mu ** 2 / 2 * sigma ** 2)):
    u = np.random.random(loc=mu, scale=sigma, size=100)
    plt.hist(u, histtype='bar', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

And for the error...

by `if y < 1./(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(mu**2/2*sigma**2)):`
what do you mean a list of number is smaller than a number?
all of them? or any of tham?
depends on either case, you can use y.all or y.any

Comment: This should be a comment (asking the OP for clarification), not an answer.

Comment: the maximum point of the PDF is at `x=0` and `y = 1./(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(mu**2/2*sigma**2))`, hence, when `y < 1./(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(mu**2/2*sigma**2))` it will plot the histogram

Comment: Also, this doesnt produce a histogram, only the PDF curve

Comment: When any of `y` are less than the function or when all of `y` are?

Comment: @JamieBull when all of `y` are less than the function

Comment: Also, I think it should be `y <=` - sorry